# About "Snap election"

Tags: word-usage

Thank you for your continuous support to the EELs including me.

Could someone kindly confirm me.

[When I was reading this article, I encountered this phrase.](http://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2017/06/09/532232560/after-u-k-election-the-only-certainty-in-britain-is-uncertainty)

> After calling a **snap election** in April in anticipation of a landslide,

I guess this phrase **snap election** would mean PM May intended to obtain
**quickly** the further number of seats in the House of Common so that they are going to be much stronger for the preparation of the Brexit?

Thank you kindly. ( Really )

Sincerely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [snap election](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_election) is described in Wikipedia as:

> an election called earlier than expected.

Further, the article describes the specific procedures relating to the **snap election** in several countries and gives some examples.